# CollectionViewSource binding doesn't work with NavigationCacheMode

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, collectionviewsource

I have a very basic setup:

In my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
```

In my XAML:

```
<Page NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"
    ...>
    ...
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CVS"
                          x:Key="CVS"
                          Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.Collection, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS}, Mode=OneWay}">
        ...
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

The problem is that when I navigate away from and then back to the page, the items list refreshes and the scroll position is lost. It's definitely an issue introduced by the `CollectionViewSource`, since if I bind my `ListView` `ItemsSource` to `Collection` directly it works perfectly.

Is there any way to get `CollectionViewSource` to play nicely with caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Collection {get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<object>();
```

You can also try use Binding not x:Bind

Comment: Huh. Using `Binding` instead of `x:Bind` fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: @RareNCool The problem was not with *Binding/x:Bind* - with both will work fine. Your original code lacks `{get;set;}` in your collection and as MSDN says - you can bind only to properties.

Comment: @Romasz No, I still don't have the `{ get; set; }` on it, and it works just fine with `Binding` and not with `x:Bind`. I also tried adding the `{ get; set; }` and using `x:Bind`, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @RareNCool Have you set somehow the DataContext? Is `ViewModel` a variable/property of your page?

Comment: @Romasz `<Page.DataContext><vm:MyViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" /></Page.DataContext>`.